# Possible to make superView intercept layoutSubviews: from subviews?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uiview, uikit, layoutsubviews

To allow for flexible layouts, I wanted to create a subclass UIView that overrides `layoutSubviews:` to layout all of its subviews under each other automagically and would continue to do this every time one of its subviews got resized.

However, the only way that I can think of to let the superview know that it should call `layoutSubviews:` is by overriding that method in each of its subviews, something that I would like to try and avoid (I want people to be able to add arbitrary UIViews to the superview and have this taken care of).

Is there a way for the superview to call `layoutSubviews:` whenever a subview changes its size, *without* adding any code to the subview in question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use KVO to observe the `frame` property of each of your subviews. You would need to add yourself as an observer each time a subview is added and remove the observation when a subview is removed – you can override `didAddSubview:` and `willRemoveSubview:` in your superview to do that.

```
- (void)didAddSubview:(UIView *)subview {
    [subview addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"frame" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:nil];
}

- (void)willRemoveSubview:(UIView *)subview {
    [subview removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"frame"];
}

- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context {
    if ([keyPath isEqualToString:@"frame"]) {
         // Do your layout here...
    }
}

- (void)dealloc {
    // You might need to remove yourself as an observer here, in case
    // your subviews are still used by others
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a category to the class and try overriding `layoutSubviews:` from within the category. (This technique [has been suggested for customizing navigation bars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4319112/how-do-i-change-the-background-of-a-uinavigationbar/4319201#4319201), and it may well work here too.)

Here's how you'd make a category, [taken from my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6934637/overwriting-uinavigationbar-to-set-a-default-titleview/6934790#6934790). In your case, remember to substitute `UIView` for `UINavigationController`.

Hit Command+N or open the "New File" dialog. Next, choose "Objective-C category" from the Cocoa Touch menu:

[image: Creating a category]

Click Next and you will be prompted to enter the name of the class that you would like to add methods to as a category. It should look something like this:

[image: Making a Category on the NavBar]

Then, you should end up with a save file dialog. A quick note about convention here. Convention is to name a category after the original class, the plus sign, and then a description of what you're adding. Here's what yours might look like:

[image: Category Naming Convention]

Once you save your file, you will need get something like this:

[image: Empty Category]

**Edit:**

If you want to go ahead and do this without a category, then your best bet is to make a subclass of UIView and then subclass *that* class wherever you want your custom behavior. Another advantage over a category is that your method will only work where you explicitly use the custom class. In categories, the method gets added everywhere.

Good luck!

Comment: Good answer, but to the wrong question. I already know how to make categories and I edited my original question because I have since learned that overriding methods in categories is a big no-no. Subclassing is how you should do this. The real question is: Is there a way for the superview to automatically call `layoutSubviews:` when a subview changes its size, _without_ adding any code to the subviews?

Comment: I'd suggest making a "two" level hierarchy then. Customize the method once in the first subclass and then subclass `that`.

Comment: That's what I figured as well, but I was wondering if there was a more elegant solution than changing all the subviews to subclass `that`. I'll give it some more time to see if someone else has another idea. An answer from you that says 'No, it's not.' would get accepted after that ;) Thanks for the comment.

Comment: @Spacy Sure, no problem. I'll edit my answer, so you can accept it if you end up going with that. ;-)